# Finding the interval between two java.util.date

Tags: java, datetime, java.util.date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

hi, I have two object of type java.util.date.

Date StartDate;
Date EndDate;

Both object have a date and specified time. I need to find the interval between them in hours, minutes and seconds. I can do it in someways but i was thinking that my technique is not the best.

So what tech would u have used for this operation in Java

Comment: What technique are you using now.

Comment: getting the diff between the date first then hours, minutes and then seconds and then combining all together

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) can handle this stuff for you. See, in particular, [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html) and [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html).

```
import org.joda.*;
import org.joda.time.*;

// interval from start to end
DateTime start = new DateTime(2004, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
System.out.println(period.getYears() + " years, " + period.getMonths() + " months, " + period.getWeeks() + " weeks, " + period.getDays() + ", days");
```

The above will print: 0 years, 0 months, 1 weeks, 0 days

Answer (score 15):

The most basic approach would use something like:

```
long interval = EndDate.getTime() - StartDate.getTime();
```

you'll get the number of milliseconds between the events. Then it's a matter of converting that into the hours, minutes and seconds.